# Prevent concurrent ajax requests, make them wait

Tags: javascript, ajax, concurrency, promise, axios

My client-side Javascript app needs a certain data structure from the server side ("lists"). Several different places in the app need access to the lists. On startup, these places all make the request, which results in several concurrent requests to the server for the same data structure.

I'd like to issue only one request to the server and have all of requesters simply get a promise that resolves when the request comes back.

I think the method is to create an array or stack of promises. If the first request is in-flight, then each subsequent request causes a promise to get created and added to the stack. When the response comes back, the system runs through the stack and resolves all the promises with the result.

The problem is that I can't figure out the right syntax to get this to work. This is what I  have so far:

```
let lists = [];
let loading = false;
let promises = [];

function getLists() {
  if (lists.length > 0) {
    // return cached copy
    return Promise.resolve(lists);
  }

  /*
  This method can get called several times in quick succession on startup.
  To prevent sending multiple requests to the server, we maintain 
  a stack of promises. If there is already a request in-flight, then just
  add a promise to the stack and return it. Then resolve all promises
  in the stack when the request returns.
  */
  let prom = new Promise();  // BAD, NOT ALLOWED
  promises.push(prom);
  if (!loading) {
    callListsApi(); // async call, resolves promises
  }
  return prom;
}

function callListsApi() {
  loading = true;
  axios.get("/lists").then(
    response => {
      loading = false;
      if (!response.data || response.data.length == 0) {
        lists = [];
      } else {
        lists = response.data;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
        promises[i].resolve(lists); // give all the callers their lists
      }
      promises = [];
    },
    error => {
      loading = false;
      util.handleAxiosError(error);
      let msg = util.getAxiosErrorText(error);
      for (let i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
        promises[i].reject(msg);
      }
      promises = [];
    }
  );
}
```

This doesn't work because you can't create a bare Promise() without putting some kind of executor function in it.

How can I rewrite this so it works?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The answer isn't to create a stack of promises. It's just to return to each requestor the same promise over and over. We maintain one main promise, which exists only when a request is in-flight. This is way simpler.

```
let lists = [];
let listPromise = null;

function getLists() {
  if (lists.length > 0) {
    // return cached copy
    return Promise.resolve(lists);
  }

  if (listPromise != null) {
    // if we get here, then there is already a request in-flight
    return listPromise;
  }

  listPromise = callListsApi();
  return listPromise;
}

function callListsApi() {
  return axios.get("/lists").then(
    response => {
      if (!response.data || response.data.length == 0) {
        lists = [];
      } else {
        lists = response.data;
      }
      listPromise = null;
      return lists;
    },
    error => {
      util.handleAxiosError(error);
      listPromise = null;
      return util.getAxiosErrorText(error);
    }
  );
}
```